# Theme a taxonomy terms page

Tags: taxonomy-terms, theming, panels

How do I theme the tag/taxonomyterm page on my site? Can I use a  panels page for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use panels. Heres a good guide to setting up page manager with panels.

http://drupal.org/node/1582906

or you could use templates...

> ```
> taxonomy-term--[vocabulary-machine-name|tid].tpl.php
> base template: taxonomy-term.tpl.php
> ```
>
> Theme hook suggestions are made based on these factors, listed from
>   the most specific template to the least. Drupal will use the most
>   specific template it finds:
>
> ```
> taxonomy-term--tid.tpl.php
> taxonomy-term--vocabulary-machine-name.tpl.php
> taxonomy-term.tpl.php
> ```
>
> Note that underscores in a vocabulary's machine name are replaced by
>   hyphens.

See: http://drupal.org/node/1089656