# How to control a taxonomy view's output?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, theming

On the page referenced below, the two blocks to the left are separate views that represent two different taxonomy terms: "fence type" and "application."

[J.C. Greene Rail Fencing photos page](http://fence.ckasdf.net/photos)

I want to be able to add a new page of photos each job and be able to label type with something like "2 Rail" and application with "Horse fence" for example. But the views need to be dynamic, so that if a new type/application is used, it is added to the list to the left and the styles applied as desired.

For example, if a new fence is installed, and its application is to keep cattle in a field, then I might put "Cattle fence" in the application field, so a new item would be added to the Application block, and upon clicking "Cattle fence," the visitor would see a grid showing one job with one picture (later to see more jobs as more cattle fences are done). Upon clicking the one picture, it would go to that job's page with the slideshow, as shown by the link below (which is what I want to see when clicking on the 2 Rail link in fence type).

[2 Rail test view](http://fence.ckasdf.net/photos/2rail-test)

To get an idea of the view configuration for each block, check out this image:
[image: View configuration for each block on the page]
(Right click & click 'view image' to see the full size.)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to do a couple complex things: 1) use contextual filters to choose which term to show and 2) then you're trying to theme certain taxonomy term pages. Once you've got stuff set up in a way that uses these concepts, you should be able to accomplish your end goal (*But the views need to be dynamic, so that if a new type/application is used, it is added to the list to the left and the styles applied as desired.*) relatively easily.

This is a good basic introduction into Views Contextual Filters: http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/using-drupal-contextual-filters-views

As for theming taxonomy term pages, I think everyone has different ideas on how to best to do that, but if you've already got these three views set up, it might be easiest to use Panels (https://drupal.org/project/panels) and drop those existing views into a panel that is context-based. Of course, Panels comes with its own learning curve, so it might not actually be that easy (though here is a basic introduction for something like what you're trying to do: https://drupal.org/node/1582906). And maybe I'm over-complicating this by assuming you want to theme your pages; maybe contextual filters were all you needed?

Just in case, here are some other ways of theming taxonomy pages:

- override taxonomy-term.tpl.php (the basics of overrides: https://drupal.org/node/173880)
- Display Suite: https://drupal.org/project/ds

I'm sure there are a bunch of other ways too, but that's all I've got off the top of my head for now. And I'm sure someone else will chime in with more options soon.

Also, here are some other links that you might find useful:

- [How to theme each nodes in a taxonomy term page seperately in drupal 7](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/88289/how-to-theme-each-nodes-in-a-taxonomy-term-page-seperately-in-drupal-7)
- [Theme a taxonomy terms page](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/53523/theme-a-taxonomy-terms-page)
- [Overriding the default taxonomy page with a view in Drupal 7](http://www.webbykat.com/comment/497)